# How do I send an internal notification in UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to figure out how to send an internal notification between objects inside of a UWP app. The analogy would be NSNotification in iOS. This is not a push notification or anything that goes outside of my app, just a way for me to send a message between objects without requiring them to have a reference to each other. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Prism, you can use the EventAggregator. If you are using vanilla, then you have to write it yourself using Weakreference. [Prism Eventaggregator](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mediator pattern to solve your problem, but I recommend you to use mvvm light framework which has a built in Messenger class which does exactly what you need:

http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger